# How can we have more conversation in chat?

Tags: discussion

What are some ideas for promoting our chat room, which seems abandoned?

We have a chat room that people don't seem to visit much, yet it could really encourage participation in the site.

What do you think we can do to improve chat participation and get more of a community feel happening?

For example, one of the features of chat is the ability to schedule a particular time for an 'event' that we can advertise on the site and get people interested.

How about the 'event' idea? If you agree, what topics would you like to discuss? And, what time would be better?

To became I propose an event each day for a week. The following program is only a draft that anybody can change the way they like:

- 月, 00:00 GMT: Welcome on ELL!
- 火, 22:00 GMT: How ELL works!
- 水, 20:00 GMT: Becoming community!
- 木, 18:00 GMT: Is EL&U still necessary!
- 金, 16:00 GMT: Having our own Blog!